# Windows 10 - GIT issues with cloning/pulling/pushing

Tags: windows-10, bash, ssh, git, openssh

I've got an strange issue. Since I updated my GIT on my Windows 10 machine, I get the error below.

I use GIT for Windows with Bash.

If I run GIT Bash with administrator rights then everything works fine. But when I run it normally I'll get the following error:

```
16:40   Update failed
            CreateProcessW failed error:193
            ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: Unknown error
            git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
            Could not read from remote repository.

            Please make sure you have the correct access rights
            and the repository exists.
```

I tried much things like changing PATH variables, re-install GIT...

Tried many things on the internet but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here?: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for your comment. Yes I've tried the instructions but unfortunately it didn't work. (As I said in my question: When I run GIT bash as administrator GIT works like a charm)